# Stop expanded content to appear when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar with numbers that expands on hover, to show text beside it. But when I refresh the page, for a split second the 'hidden' content shows before collapsing again. How can I stop this from happening?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="sidebar">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><span>01</span> HomePage</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>02</span> SubPage 1</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>03</span> SubPage 2</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>04</span> SubPage 3</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>05</span> SubPage 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width:80px;
  height:100vw;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:100;
  background:#111;
  color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.sidebar ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px;
  list-style:none;
}
.sidebar a span {
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
.sidebar a {
  color:#fff;
  font-size:14px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebar').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'110px'},500);
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'35px'},500);
    }).trigger('mouseleave');
});
```

What did I do wrong? And how can I fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `width: 35px` change in your default CSS and remove the `$.trigger('mouseleave')` line.

You could also do this with just CSS, btw. And if you add `.stop()` before each `$.animate()`, it will keep the menu from opening/closing over and over if you hover over/off the menu really fast.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidebar').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      width: '110px'
    }, 500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      width: '35px'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width:35px;
  height:100vw;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:100;
  background:#111;
  color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.sidebar ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px;
  list-style:none;
}
.sidebar a span {
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
.sidebar a {
  color:#fff;
  font-size:14px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><span>01</span> HomePage</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>02</span> SubPage 1</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>03</span> SubPage 2</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>04</span> SubPage 3</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>05</span> SubPage 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here it is in just CSS. Much simpler.

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width:35px;
  height:100vw;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:100;
  background:#111;
  color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: width .5s;
}
.sidebar:hover {
  width: 110px;
}
.sidebar ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px;
  list-style:none;
}
.sidebar a span {
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
.sidebar a {
  color:#fff;
  font-size:14px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><span>01</span> HomePage</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>02</span> SubPage 1</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>03</span> SubPage 2</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>04</span> SubPage 3</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>05</span> SubPage 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael! Especially because you included the CSS version. I'll definitely be working on that one.